# Stop channel.basic_consume if the connection is idle/Not consuming from long time

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am having a use case in which i want get the last idle time(last message processed time) of a pika consumer(pika.BlockingConnection).
**Usecase:**
If the last processed time is greater than Threshold time(ex: 1 hr). I want the consumer to get exited or have a callback method to decide on what i need to do? Like sending a notification to a user.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pika supports a [timeout callback.](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/connection.html#pika.connection.Connection.add_timeout)

You could add this callback at the end of each message receipt, keeping the reference to it, and removing it at the start of each message receipt.

```
def close_connec():
    # close here

timer_id = None

def on_message(chan, method, props, body):
    if timer_id is not None:
        chan.connection.remove_timeout(timer_id)
    # process message
    timer_id = chan.connection.add_timeout(3600, close_connec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using this code and its works fine for me.but only if i want to use the timeout callback only to exit/close the connection.What if i want to send a notification and again resume the consuming? I am getting a wierd issue wen i try to resume.The notification message has been printed the number of messages it has consumed.Here is the reference code: (https://gist.github.com/rohitvernekar/a79faded6261feaca82e4ac6b0292be0)

Comment: Looks like the timeout callback function has  not been removed properly.Any way to do this?  @kevin-m-granger

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: My mistake! I thought the docs implied that you passed the function again. Instead, add_timeout will give you an opaque identifier for the timeout.

Comment: The code which u suggested works very good only if i want to close the connection/exit the consumer.But my use case is to send a mail to the user after the timeout and resume consuming.But the timeout function is getting called for the number of messages consumed.
Attaching the logs here: https://gist.github.com/rohitvernekar/10a0718b955e8dc4d9bf83b0a37eb64a
From the above logs the notification is getting sent 5 times.I want it to be send only if the last message consumed gets timeout

Comment: The code I had before incorrectly removed the timeout. Did you try it with the new code?

Comment: Great :) Updated the working code for others reference.