# Python Pika disconnect channel on iddle

Tags: rabbitmq, channel, pika

I'm having problems to understand how I can set a timeout for an iddle channel. I found this answer:

[Stop channel.basic_consume if the connection is idle/Not consuming from long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884655/stop-channel-basic-consume-if-the-connection-is-idle-not-consuming-from-long-tim)

But the variable timer_id gets out of scope inside my on_message method.

Is there a way to disconnect a channel when no message has arrive to the queue in a given time?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

sure I can help you with that. For such situations I opted for using a channel.consume() method,this return an iterator tuple of (method, properties, body) and when the queue empties and the timeout has been reached, it returns an (None, None, None) tuple.
Just check for not None and bam! there you have your closing method plus a disconnection:

```
for method, prop, body in channel.consume(queue='Q_test_timeout',
                                          no_ack=True,
                                          exclusive=True,
                                          inactivity_timeout=3):
```

[Docs](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/adapters/blocking.html)

Comment: Also please wrap that generator inside a try/except block to catch the timeout exception since when timeout is reached, a simple None is returned , making the variables assignement to fail.